# UWP drag and drop onto WebView

Tags: image, webview, drag-and-drop, win-universal-app

Is there any possibility to drop an external file onto a WebView in a Windows UWP app?

I know about :

```
AllowDrop="True" Drop="WebView_Drop" DragOver="WebView_DragOver"
```

I was able to copy files that i dragged into the clipboard and use it then on other items like displaying them as an image etc.

Besides that I don't see any way to interact directly with the webview or am i wrong? The current page the webview is showing is allowing to drop media files into it and i would like to use that feature in the webview...

Comment: From the document drop event is not supported. More info, see [WebView](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview.aspx).

Comment: @JaydenGu That is right unfortunately, thank you. Strangely VS2015 let's me put that event in xaml without giving me a problem. :(

Answer (score 1):

WebView does not support drop event. WebView doesn’t support most of the user input events inherited from UIElement, such as KeyDown, KeyUp, and PointerPressed. A common workaround is to use InvokeScriptAsync with the JavaScript eval function to use the HTML event handlers, and to use window.external.notify from the HTML event handler to notify the application using WebView.ScriptNotify